# Transform Method of graphics class in Codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone

I am unable to find alternative to Transform Method of graphics class in CodenameOne. I have tried using Graphics setTransform Method but am unable to get that desired functionality. Can you please help with this. Thank you

```
AffineTransform saveAT = g2d.getTransform();
g2d.transform(getmyTranslation());      
g2d.transform(getmyRotation());         
g2d.fillRect((int)(0-getSize()/2), (int)(0-getSize()/2), getSize(), getSize());         
for (Object f : obj)
{
   f.draw(g2d);
}       
g2d.setTransform(saveAT);
```

We do not have g2d.transform in CodenameOne

Comment: Can you elaborate?  What is the desired functionality that you can't get?

Comment: To further clarify, can you post some Java2D or equivalent code that you can't reproduce in Codename One and we'll try to help.

Comment: FYI I suggest posting a comment after making an edit otherwise we don't get a notification. Also I would suggest using a Java tag for syntax highlighting in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The affine transform is built directly into graphics so you don't need the first few lines at all:

```
AffineTransform saveAT = g2d.getTransform();
g2d.transform(getmyTranslation());      
g2d.transform(getmyRotation());
```

You can just do:

```
g2d.rotate(degrees, pivotX, pivotY);
```

The fill rect should be practically identical:

```
g2d.fillRect((int)(0-getSize()/2), (int)(0-getSize()/2), getSize(), getSize());
```

Draw should also work nicely for `Shape` objects:

```
for (Object f : feet)
{
   f.draw(g2d);
}
```

Restoring the affine like this isn't necessary:

```
g2d.setTransform(saveAT);
```

Just do this instead:

```
g2d.resetAffine();
```